# Is tkinter dropdown list over text field possible?

Tags: tkinter, pyside

I was doing some autocompletion stuff in Python&tkinter and it appears that I've stuck with trying to explain what I really want to achieve.

I'm looking to do the exact thing as on this screenshot - dropdown list over a text field.
Is this possible in tkinter? in pyside??

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOg5g.png

Comment: There is `QCompleter` in PySide/Qt... Maybe that's what you are looking for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You have two choices:

1. Create a listbox as a child of the text widget, and use the `place` geometry manager to place it directly under the cursor. This has the disadvantage that the listbox can't exceed the borders of the window. This means that if you are at the very bottom of the window you'll need to place the listbox above the entry rather than below
2. Create a toplevel with `overrideredirect` set to True. You can then use the `geometry` method to place it right below the cursor. This has the advantage of being able to float over the text widget, but requires a little more attention to detail so that the user can't move the text widget away from the popup.

Comment: first one does not look like what I've shown because of window decorations, can I disable those?

Comment: The first one should have no window decorations because it is just a listbox. The second one, like I suggested, needs to have the `overrideredirect` flag set, which will turn off all window devorations.